# @XmlElement does not work when used in kotlin

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations, kotlin

When I serialize an instance of class `ReturnValue`, I found that `@XmlElement` doesn't work. the generated xml still had a tag of `<summary>`, not `<comment>`.

the ReturnValue class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class ReturnValue(val type: String,
                       @XmlElement(name="comment")
                       val summary: String){
    constructor(): this(type="java.lang.Object", summary="no summary")
}
```

the test program:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ReturnValue::class.java)
    val marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller()
    marshaller.marshal(
        ReturnValue(type = "java.lang.Object",summary = "hello"),
        System.out)
}
```

and the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><returnValue><type>type2</type><summary>hello</summary></returnValue>
```

So, I want to change `<summary>` to `<comment>`. How can I do that?

Comment: you can edit your question to add details, rather than putting in comments.

Answer (score 25):

JAXB is a Java API, which expects things to look the way that Java normally does things, and Kotlin does things slightly differently.

To annotate the parameter so that it looks correct to JAXB, you have to use `@field:XmlElement` so that the annotation is put on the Java field that the Kotlin parameter translates to, like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class ReturnValue(val type: String,
                       @field:XmlElement(name = "comment") val summary: String) {
  constructor() : this(type = "java.lang.Object", summary = "no summary")
}
```

More information: [Annotation Use-site Targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) in the Kotlin documentation.

Comment: this worked for me instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56011795/281191

Answer (score 0):

If the xml tag and property is written in caps, you can leave out the field-annotations. I had the problem while parsing xml files with some regular fields and some caps fields. `@field:XmlElement` resolves this issue, thx to @[awd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934317/awd)

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
                        <Root>
                            <Child>Text</Child>
                        </Root>"""
    val jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root::class.java)
    val unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller()
    val root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml.reader())
    println(root)

    val XML = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
                        <Root>
                            <CHILD>Text</CHILD>
                        </Root>"""
    val JAXBCONTEXT = JAXBContext.newInstance(CapsRoot::class.java)
    val UNMARSHALLER = JAXBCONTEXT.createUnmarshaller()
    val ROOT = UNMARSHALLER.unmarshal(XML.reader())
    println(ROOT)

    val xmlField = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
                        <Root>
                            <Child>Text</Child>
                        </Root>"""
    val jaxbContextField = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootField::class.java)
    val unmarshallerField = jaxbContextField.createUnmarshaller()
    val rootField = unmarshallerField.unmarshal(xml.reader())
    println(rootField)
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
data class Root(var Child: String? = null)

@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
data class CapsRoot(var CHILD: String? = null)

@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
data class RootField(@field:XmlElement var Child: String? = null)
```

Prints:

```
Root(Child=null)
CapsRoot(CHILD=Text)
RootField(Child=Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem, but my solution was that @XmlElement needs **namespace** param to be specified, if at least one upper tag has custom one. Even if this namespace is specified in @XmlRootElement